# How to the get a length in javascript from an array generated in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use jQuery to call a php function and return an array. Here is the php code:

```
  $users = array();
  $user = array();

  $user["fname"] = "Juan";
  $user["lname"] = "Perez";
  $user["uname"] = "jperez";
  $user["passwd"] = "passwd1234";
  $user["rights"] = array(
  "mod_own" => true,
  "view_all" => false,
  "mod_all" => true,
  "mod_proj" => false,
  "mod_users" => true
  ); 

  $users[1] = $user;

  $user["fname"] = "Pedro";
  $user["lname"] = "Rodriquez";
  $user["uname"] = "pedror";
  $user["passwd"] = "passwd456+";
  $user["rights"] = array(
  "mod_own" => false,
  "view_all" => true,
  "mod_all" => false,
  "mod_proj" => true,
  "mod_users" => false
  ); 

  $users[1] = $user;
  $ret["users"] = $users;
  $ret["error"] = "";

  echo json_encode($ret);
```

This is just a test code of what I really want to return. The thing is that I know that users has a length 2 here, but in the real applicaction I won't know that. I want to check its length. In the javascript that calls this function the returning object is call obj. If I say

obj.users[1]['fname']

I get the correct name and everything. What I don't know how to do is check the length of users. I have tried obj.users.length but it doesn't work.

How do I check that?

EDIT:

To see the length I used this code:

```
document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML="N de users is " + obj.users.length;
```

I got "N de users is undefined"

Comment: "it doesn't work": does it give an error, because that should work?

Comment: `obj.users.length` should work. Please show what `console.log(obj);` shows in the console

Comment: I'm very new at this. I write my code in a text editor and try it out on a webpage. How do I check the console output? As far as why it doesn't work, it is because when I try to print its value, the value printed is undefined. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Does your JavaScript run JSON.parse?  (Could you post the JavaScript?)

Comment: @AndréDion you are confusing php and js syntax, the php would be `array_push($users, $user);` or `$users[]=$user;`

Comment: @user792589 What browser are you using? in chrome you can right click on the page, select 'view source' then click on the console tab. Then reload the webpage and you will see the output from console.log, plus any js errors

Comment: I am using chrome and thanks for that. Will use it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `$users[1]` twice without setting `$users[0]`. This will output an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), which does not have a `length` property. Instead of specifying the index directly, just push your content into `$users`: `$users[] = $user`.

Comment: I don't know about your syntax for adding users (I used to use array_push($users, $user); and I used it again) but this solved it!!!! Thank you very much. Now obj.users.length works!!

Comment: My syntax is preferred as it doesn't carry the overhead of calling a function. See [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) for more information.